# Magento 2 : How to add progessive bar(>) after next button in checkout page

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I want to change text name of next button in checkout page

```
<button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
</button>
```

I wrote code in shipping.html in pub

```
     <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</button>
```

but nothing change

Any suggestion?

Comment: `<i>` tag requires closing `</i>`

Comment: its correct or not @f_martinez

Comment: TBH I don't know much about overriding Magento templates. Maybe this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100440/magento-2-override-shipping-template) will be useful.